# Configuration for import target does not exist error with for_each in import block

Tags: terraform, azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure

I have existing infrastructure that I want to manage with terraform and import into the statefile. In this case I am trying to import storage containers. The storage account itself has already been imported into the statefile.

In my main.tf I have:

```
import {
  for_each = toset(var.storage_containers)

  to = module.storage_container.azurerm_storage_container.storage_container[each.key]
  id = "https://${module.storage_account.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${each.key}"
}

module "storage_container" {
  source = "../../../modules/storage/storage_container"

  for_each = toset(var.storage_containers)

  storage_container = {
    name        = each.key
    access_type = "Private"
  }
  storage_account_name = module.storage_account.name
}
```

In variables.tf I have the storage_containers variable set with a default value, which contains the storage container names.

```
variable "storage_containers" {
  description = "List of storage containers"
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "artifact",
    "fire",
    "models",
    "security",
    "snapshots",
    "statistics",
  ]
}
```

When I run terraform plan I get the following error:

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Configuration for import target does not exist
│ 
│ The configuration for the given import
│ module.storage_container.azurerm_storage_container.storage_container["models"]
│ does not exist. All target instances must have an associated configuration
│ to be imported.
╵
```

When I rerun it the error can change by mentioning another storage container in the error message. The containers exist for sure (double checked).
I can't figure out where I am going wrong on this.

I use terraform version 1.7.1 and azurerm provider version 3.89.0.

I have tried running in locally but also via an azure devops pipeline and both give the same error.  I also tried an earlier version of terraform 1.7.0.

My expectations would of course be that the storage containers are imported into the state file.

Answer (score 2):

The import block should be:

```
import {
  for_each = toset(var.storage_containers)

  to = module.storage_container[each.key].azurerm_storage_container.storage_container
  id = "https://${module.storage_account.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${each.key}"
}
```